# Stackdriver debug issue for node.js app

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-debugger

Regardless of the browser I'm using, I can't get stackdriver debugging work. After navigating to the source for the code that runs on app engine, clicking on the gutter doesn't do anything.

I'm not using github or bitbucket or google cloud source repo, so uploaded the code from local. I noticed this msg after uploading the dist from local..did anyone succeed in setting this up?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, many use node.js apps with Stackdriver Debugger successfully.

As long as your local source code matches the deployed source code, this is a benign message.

Please email cdbg-feedback@google.com for further support.